# OpenGL / Qt - image distorted when displayed the video

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, opengl

I'm working with QT creator, C++ and OpenGL. I would like to display a video in a GUI.

Therefore I'm using the opencvwidget cpp file. Here the description

> /**  * Widget to captures frames or single images using OpenCV and
>   display them using OpenGL.  *  * This class integrates OpenCV and Qt.
>   It is a widget that can be added to  * your GUI and it can handle both
>   the capture and display of video and single  * images.  *  * The class
>   is implemented with a double buffer system: One cv::Mat holds the most
>   * recently captured image (hereafter called capture image) and another holds the image  * that is currently being displayed in the widget
>   (the display image). This allows you  * to perform processing on the
>   capture image before showing it, by first calling  * getImage(), then
>   altring it, and finally calling updateDisplay(). If you simply want  *
>   to show it right away, enable auto display (using
>   enableAutoDisplay()).  */

When I read a video, I have a problem with the display. Indeed, my picture is distorted like this:
[image]

If I use some others video, the image is correct. I tried for a couple of hours, to understand why the display is not correct and I still didn't find a solution.

I think the problem come from the application of the texture:

```
void OpenCVWidget::paintGL()
{
    if(displayImage.empty()) {
        displayImage = Mat::zeros(1, 1, CV_8UC3); // Paint a black background until we have something to show.
    }

    qglClearColor(Qt::black); // Create a nice, black background for the parts of the widget with no image.
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();

    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices.constData());
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoords.constData());
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);




    // Non-mipmap way of mapping the texture (fast and clean):
    glGenTextures(1, &texture); // Allocate a texture name.
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture); // Select our current texture.
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); // When the texture area is larger then the image, upscale using linear interpolation.
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); // When the texture area is smaller than the image, downsample using linear interpolation.

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, displayImage.cols, displayImage.rows, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, displayImage.data);

    // End of different methods, the last few lines are common for all methods.

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4); // Draw it!

    glDeleteTextures(1, &texture);

}
```

I wonder if It's not a problem of channel or something like this, But I don't know.

If someone has already handle with this kind of problem, please help me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: where does the image come from?

Comment: What's the size of the image? Try `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)` if the width is not a multiple of 4.

Comment: Wow this solution worked @RetoKoradi Thanks you so much ! This solution wouldn't have crossed my mind... Can you explain me why please ?
the size of the picture is 1226*370

Comment: I guess openGL textures normally need a power of 2 in each direction

Comment: @Micka No, that hasn't been the case for a long time. The power of 2 restriction was lifted around OpenGL 2.0.

Comment: Yeah I'm not very familiar with OpenGL yet.

Comment: @lilouch I closed this as a duplicate. See the question/answer it's now linked to. The title might sound a bit different. But if you look at the picture in that question, it looks almost the same as yours, and it sounds like the root cause was indeed the same.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Okey thanks you, I'll read the explanation. I've already searched on StackOverflow before posting but I didn't see this post.

Comment: Yes, the problem with these types of questions is often that you can't even find good enough search keywords unless you have a very good idea what the problem is. Non-trivial duplicates can serve a useful purpose because they make it more likely that other people with similar problems find the solution with a search.